# How to have multiple View Controllers linked to the same Navigation tutorial

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, relationship

I have setup a View Controller in Xcode 6 that is embedded in a navigation controller, but I want to setup another View Controller to use that same navigation controller, but when I tried to link the navigation controller to the other View Controller by using the relationship "root view controller" it connects to my new View Controller but deletes the relationship to the old View Controller. So I'm just wondering is it possible to do this or would I need a separate navigation controller for each View Controller.

Hopefully this is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. A navigationController has an array of UIViewControllers and the UIViewControllers form the navigation stack. The first item added to the stack becomes the root view controller and is never popped off the stack, as said in the documentation.

You are  changing the first controller of the stack, you are creating a totally new stack to navigate through.

You should use two navigation controllers one for each root controller

Comment: Would it be possible to have the navigation bar brought over from the first ViewController

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You need separate navigation controllers.